# How to enable a theme for all views?

Tags: cakephp, themes, cakephp-3.0

I am working on a CakePHP 3 project and I'm new to CakePHP.

I have baked a theme `MyTheme` in `plugins/MyTheme`.

I have also configured `default.ctp` in `plugins/MyTheme/src/Template/Layout/` directory and all `css` and `js` files in `plugins/MyTheme/webroot/css/` and `/plugins/MyTheme/webroot/js/` directories.

How do I enable this theme for all views (master theme) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] How do I enable this theme for all views (master theme) ?

By defining the theme to use (either via the `$theme` property (before CakePHP 3.1), or via the view builders `theme()` method) in a controller that all your applications controllers extend, which by default should be `AppController`.

Something along the lines of

```
//...

class AppController extends Controller
{
    // With CakePHP < 3.1
    public $theme = 'MyTheme';

    // With CakePHP >= 3.1
    public function beforeRender(\Cake\Event\Event $event)
    {
        $this->viewBuilder()->theme('MyTheme');
    }
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > The App Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Themes](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/themes.html)**